# adding "int" with "uint_64t"

Tags: c++, uint64

There are three variables with the following types

```
 uint64_t old_addr, new_addr;
 int delta;
```

and I want to do this assignment

```
 new_addr = old_addr + delta;
```

However the problem is, when `old_addr=915256` and `delta=-6472064`, the `new_addr` becoms `18446744069414584325`

to fix that I have to check some things:

```
 if ( delta < 0 ) {
if ( old_addr < abs(delta) )
   new_addr = 0;
    else   
       new_addr = old_addr + delta;
 }
```

Is there a better and efficient way?

Comment: I hope there is an else before the second `new_addr`... Otherwise you return to the original problem :-)

Comment: Given that you've called these variables `_addr`, are they memory addresses? If so, you should be using `intptr_t` (which is signed) and `ptrdiff_t` for `delta`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is what values `old_addr` and `new_addr` can take.  And why
they are `uint64_t`, rather than simply `int`.  The simplest expression
would be:

```
new_addr = old_addr + std::min( delta, -static_cast<int>( old_addr ) );
```

, but if `old_addr` can be greater than `INT_MAX`, this won't work.
Otherwise, the rules of mixed signed/unsigned arithmetic in C/C++ are
such that you're probably safest using explicit `if`s, and not risking
any mixed arithmetic before being sure of the values.

And note that on most machines, `abs( delta )` will still be negative if
`delta` is equal to `INT_MIN`.  To correctly handle all of the cases,
you'ld need something like:

```
if ( delta > 0 ) {
    new_addr = std::numeric_limits<uin64_t>::max() - delta > old_addr
            ?   old_addr + delta
            :   std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
} else if ( delta < 0 ) {
    new_addr = old_addr != 0 && -(delta + 1) < old_addr - 1
            ?   old_addr + delta
            :   0;
} else {
    new_addr = old_addr;
}
```

(Just off the top of my head.  There could easily be an off by one error
in there.)

Answer (score 4):

This is called saturated addition, and some processors have special machine instructions for that. You could extract that code into an inline function, and depending on the target execution environment, use the machine instruction.

Instead of `abs(delta)` you can simply write `-delta`, since you already know that `delta < 0`.

Comment: but I have to be sure that old_addr is smaller than absolute value of delta. Otherwise, the saturation addition can not be detected

Comment: Neither `abs(delta)` nor `-delta` work if `delta == MIN_INT`.  At least on a twos complement machine.

Answer (score 0):

This code is very simple and takes care of overflow in both directions.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static uint64_t saturated_add(uint64_t a, int delta) {
  uint64_t result = a + delta;
  if (delta < 0 && result > a) {
    return 0;
  } else if (delta > 0 && result < a) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}

int main() {
  assert(saturated_add(915256, -6472064) == 0);
  assert(saturated_add(100, -99) == 1);
  assert(saturated_add(100, -100) == 0);
  assert(saturated_add(100, -101) == 0);
  assert(saturated_add(UINT64_C(0x1111222233334444), -0x33334445) == UINT64_C(0x11112221FFFFFFFF));
  assert(saturated_add(-5, 6) == UINT64_C(-1));
  assert(saturated_add(-5, 5) == UINT64_C(-1));
  assert(saturated_add(-5, 4) == UINT64_C(-1));
  assert(saturated_add(-5, 3) == UINT64_C(-2));
  return 0;
}
```